# WCF "The given key was not present in the dictionary"

Tags: c#, wcf, dictionary

I'm getting this error even though I'm not using a Dictionary, and what's weird is that it's when I call the service.

```
wsSoapClient client = null;
try
{
    client = new wsSoapClient();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{ 
    // - Error in the web.config
}

try
{
    SendData sendData = new SendData();
    sendData.finishDate = myVar.FinishDate;
    sendData.startDate = myVar.StartDate;
    // - Other fields

    // - This lines throw the error below
    ClientResult result = client.FinishCourse(sendData);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // - Message: The given key was not present in the dictionary.
}
```

The stack trace:

``` StackTrace: at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary``2.get_Item(TKey key)
at Project.Model.CourseService.FinishCourse(XmlNode node) ```

The service is up to date, and I couldn't find info on this anywhere else. There's two similar questions on SO but they are about Silverlight and I couldn't figure a relation between this (regular C# WCF calling a service) and the solutions.

What causes this and how do I fix it?

**(Edit) More Info**: The binding is a basicHttpBinding, http only.

**Edit²**: The [WSDL](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7U7ga63UcYRbFRXcU1YX0VqOUU/view?usp=sharing).

**Edit³**: Found the issue. Apparently, there was already another error (a value larger than the field allows), the service was returning an **error** but for some reason, WCF didn't take that as error and didn't threw the exception, and I'm guessing it tried to proceed normally, causing this dictionary error since the XML is not what is was expecting.

Comment: can you post the wsdl?

Comment: @ManOnAMission It's a huge XML and it's access is blocked via IP so I can't, sorry. The contract was generated from an earlier version of Visual Studio (the one the machine with access to the URL has, 2010 Web Express) so I think that might be the issue...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your service method is not the one throwing the exception, then it might be the case with the deserialization of the soap message (i.e request object) that happens on the service side.

Check your code(or wsdl) for SendData and see if there are non nullable properties which you are not setting in the request object i.e. sendData object. Missing required properties might cause issues during deserialization.

Posting the code of SendData and\or FinishCourse service method would be great in analyzing the possible issue.

Comment: Added the WSDL, or did you mention the Reference.cs file? I've looked through it, but the class that uses it only has 8~ or so properties, `int`s and `string`s. It does have one `IList<string>`, so if I were to guess that'd be where the issue is, but other functions also have this same class and they work fine...